# Phonegap somehow breaks app when launch the second time

Tags: android, cordova

I have android Phonegap app, simple listview. When I launch it for the first time, UI seems ok, images are loaded. But when I exit and launch it again - UI is in the mess, images don't get loaded. So I need to reboot device to repair it. 
 My question is - if Phonegap caches the app data, is there a way to disable this cache and clear loaded data on exit?

UPD: I use Cordova 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you set dimensions with Javascript? If so, the dimensions are not always set on javascript loaded through header section - they are delayed on some Android vertsions. You may need to throttle the initializing your app dimensions.

Comment: Even images don't get loaded. Though after some hours it somehow self-repairs and if I run app, everything is fine. I guess it's bug.

Comment: May be late answer but I will chime in anyway... It still may be coming down whether you position your UI with Javascript. The activity may be paused but not destroyed. See if killing the process helps with loading images.

Anyway, setting dimensions with Javascript is not reliable in Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: I'm actually having this issue at the moment and I'm not setting any dimensions. @Roman were you able to resolve this